# Using pry with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, pry

New to Ruby and Sinatra.

I'm trying to use pry within a Sinatra controller (want to be able to take a look at what params is returning to me). I added a 'binding.pry' inside of the Post request, but it's not working. I know I need to require 'pry' but should that be placed in the controller file, config.ru or environment file in order to work properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on where you want to use pry. If you want it to work everywhere in your Sinatra project, then just add it to your Gemfile.

```
group :development, :test do
   gem 'pry'
end
```

I would recommend limiting the environments to :development and :test, since you will be doing your debugging there.

You can also require it in the top of your application like so:

```
require 'pry'
```